# Android Change image depending on a global variable

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, variables

the question is simple.

I have 2 images in PNG format (logo1.png and logo2.png) in the project. Currently the project is loaded (in a imageview) the logo1.png, but I would do, depending on the value of a variable load the logo1.png or load logo2.png in imageview control.

The project currently has 20 Activitys with this picture (each with its own layout in XML), I will not be changing code on the 20 screens, it could do with a simple instruction to verify the value of the variable, but would have to make change in the 20 screens.

wonder if there is no way to do that depending on the value of a variable, change the image in the ImageView.

will be able to access the value of the variable from the same XML?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused, but I'll give it a shot.

Yes, you can have a global variable where you define which image will load. But from my understanding, you would need to change the code in the activities that load that image to make them load the image dynamically via the code-behind.

I suspect it would be something like this:

1. Get info from the database indicating what value to load.
2. `SetImageToLoad(someValue)`
3. In each class that loads the image, you'll need to retrieve the value that you previously set in Step #2.

   public class HelperClass
   {

   ```
   int resIDOfImageToLoad =  0;

   public static void SetImageToLoad(String imageName)
   {
       if(imageName.equals("abc"))
       {
           resIDOfImageToLoad = R.id.abc;
       }
       else if(imageName.equals("xyz"))
       {
           resIDOfImageToLoad = R.id.xyz;
       }
    }

    public static int GetResourceIDOfImageToLoad()
    {
        return resIDOfImageToLoad;
    }
   ```

   }

Then in the class that needs to load the image, you would call something like this

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(...)
myImage.setImageResource(HelperClass.GetResourceIDOfImageToLoad());
```

Comment: that's right, that's what I intended to do, but I have to do on every screen and that's what I wanted to avoid, if no other way, then I will have to do it this way.

Comment: Well since you are reading the value from a database, it needs to be changed/loaded at runtime, which means each image needs to try and figure out what image to show. So in the end, yes, you need changes to each activity, but beyond the initial work, you would only need to change one piece of code to add different images.

Comment: that's right, now I realized that there is not much to change, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly. Create a new XML View of the image e.g. logo.xml and use it in all 20 Views and when you want to change that image change only in the logo.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a base Activity class, you can define a method `getLogo()` in the base class that would return the png (or the filename or whatever suits you). Then just call that method when inflating the layout.

Initially, you'd have to change all the Activities, but after that you just need to change the base class if you decide to change the logic that chooses which image to show. (If this is not what you intended, please clarify your question).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Style or Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html). Read over the section that talks about inheritance, and declare a separate `Style` for each logo. You can then reuse the `Style` in each one of your XML files.

If you decide to programmatically determine which image to use, you can declare a `static` method that can be used application wide to determine which logo to use in each Context, then `setImageResource()` accordingly.